# How does decalmachine work "under the hood"?

Tags: texturing, displacement

I have a question i cant get an answer to on any of the blender forums i have asked on. I am interested in learning how an add like decalmachine works under the hood.

I am trying to create the kind of decals you get in addons like decalmachine. Some of them have been quite achievable with some work, while others are not working at all. I have added a video by Josh Gambrell to ilustrate what i am trying to do. At 24 minutes into the video, he adds a decal that looks like it is going at least a centimeter into the mesh. At 32.10 in the video he fixes the colour so it looks decent. Oh well, he says it is abit jagged on the edges but from afar it looks ok. Also, just before 31 minutes he adds a couple of decals that looks like it cuts pretty deep into the mesh looking pretty awesome.

I have tried to reproduce this in blender but i am having a really hard time. My method is to create textures with height and/or normal maps.
One issue i am facing is that it is dificult to produce a displacement free of artifacts. I have got abit further on this after getting some help but i am not quite there. But if i manage to fix taht completely i will stil be stuck with a more troublesome issue, that the displaced decal will intersect with the mesh i use it on. That way most of the displacement will be hidden on the backside of the mesh. That way the ilusion of depth is broken, Now, i dont know if this is the correct method, or if i am doing it the wrong way around or what! Maybe the way i have percieved that this works is wrong? What i do now is that decalmachine utilizes tools and actions that are in blender already so i believe it should be possible to do this with blender alone, though of course through a more complicated process.

So this is more than one single question on how to fix the spesific issue i am having right now. All you can throw at me to fix this, and other issues concerning creating this in blender is welcomed. I know some will say that it is not possible in blender and that might hold some truth. But for a large part, decalmachine utilizes tools and functions that are already in blender. So i believe it is posible to at least create a result not far from what you get from decalmachine. Of course in a much more complicated way though.

I have added two images. One shows how the displaced mesh looks. This is a gradient created in gimp with a smooth transition from white to black. It is not good enough so i am looking for other methods. Maybe procedurally in blender?

The other inage shows what i mean when the displacement is broken because it intersects with the mesh. Is the way i percieve this to work completely wrong?
Anyway, everything you can throw at me to get me in the right direction is welcome. Even though this is an issue i am facing right now, information to face similar issues later could be useful.

And finally, thank you for reading through the whole thing:)[
[![
[image]

Comment: One issue, it seems that i cannot add more than one image! Not sure how to show the last image. Also, the link to the video failed so i here it is if it is posible. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8UH8UBKO8w&t=1914s

Comment: Hello, have you tried reaching out to the creators directly ? Generally this should be the surest way to ensure you get the desired response

Comment: The addon creators? I think i can be percieved as someone who is trying to make them teach me about it, then create a competing addon with pretty much the same features.

Comment: Afaik, decalmachine uses parallax shaders for faking depth.

Comment: So we are speaking faked depth, not geometry displacement?

Comment: Add-ons in blender are python scripts. If you want to learn how they work "under the hood", just open the script in a text editor.

Comment: If i knew code i would have done it long ago, and i wouldnt have to ask here or anywhere else! So this is nothing i can "just do"!

Comment: @MortenFjellheim, yes! 'fake depth'.. You can read about it in the DM documentation: https://machin3.io/DECALmachine/docs/decals/

Comment: Thanks for that:)